# How to access a request within a plugin?

Tags: hapi.js

Is there a way to access a request (whether there's an associated route or not) in a Hapi plugin?

I know I have access to `server` in my plugin, but it seems if I attempt to set any event handlers within the context of a plugin to get at the request, they never fire.

For example, the following works as expected:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');    
var server = new Hapi.Server();    

server.connection({port: 3000});

server.start(function () {
  console.log('hapi server started @ ', server.info.uri);
});

server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
  console.log(request);
  return reply.continue();
});

server.route({                                          
  path: '/',                                           
  method: 'GET',               
  handler: function (request, reply) {    
    reply({yo: 'noid'});                  
    server.log(['trace'], request);    
  }                                    
});
```

If I try the same thing within the context of a plugin, nothing happens:

```
// Hapi App

var Hapi = require('hapi');    
var server = new Hapi.Server();    

server.register({ register: require('samplePlugin') }, function (error) {
  if(error) {
    console.log('failed to load plugin:', error);
  }
});

server.connection({port: 3000});

server.start(function () {
  console.log('hapi server started @ ', server.info.uri);
});

server.route({                                          
  path: '/',                                           
  method: 'GET',               
  handler: function (request, reply) {    
    reply({yo: 'noid'});                  
    server.log(['trace'], request);    
  }                                    
});

// Hapi Plugin
var samplePlugin = function (server, options, next) {                                                        
  'use strict';                                                                                        

  server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {                                                  
    console.log(request);                                                                              
    return reply.continue();                                                                           
  });                                                                                                  

  next();                                                                                              
};                                                                                                     

exports.register = logger;                                                                             
exports.register.attributes = { pkg: require('./package.json') };
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  I'd also be happy to hear alternative approaches.  Maybe I'm heading down the wrong path (I'm new to Hapi).  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `server.register()` is asynchronous, however you start the server outside its callback. You need to make sure that server is started only when plugins are registered. You can fix your code easily by moving the `server.start()` part into the callback of `server.register()`:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({port: 3000});

server.route({
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply({yo: 'noid'});
    server.log(['trace'], request);
  }
});

server.register({ register: require('./plugin') }, function (error) {
  if(error) {
    console.log('failed to load plugin:', error);
  }

  server.start(function () {
    console.log('hapi server started @ ', server.info.uri);
  });
});
```

Comment: how can we access request.payload in onRequest server.ext i am always getting request.payload as null